# OSX default file permissions when copying/saving files

Tags: macos, permission, apache

Every time I save a file from a web browser or copy files from our local server to my machine, the default permission "for everyone" is set to `none`.
I'm a web developer. Files that are non-readable will not be displayed when accessed from an Apache server.

That means I always have to go through every file manually and change their permissions.

Is there a way to tell OSX that all files should be readable?

Answer (score 1):

From the terminal you can use the `chmod` command to change permissions. In this case the command would be `chmod a+r *`. This would change all files in a folder. If you want to do this from the Finder, you would have to create a service. You could then select a group of files and change all of them at once. The instructions are given below.

1. Open the Automator application.
2. Select "Service" and click "Choose".
3. Drag the action "Run AppleScript" to where it says "Drag actions or
   files here to build your workflow".
4. Set "Service receives selected `text` in `any application`" to
   "Service receives selected `files or folders` in `Finder`".
5. Replace the code

   ```
   on run {input, parameters}

       (* Your script goes here *)

       return input
   end run
   ```

   with

   ```
   on run {input, parameters}
       try
           repeat with currentfile in input
               try
                   do shell script "chmod a+r " & quoted form of POSIX path of currentfile
               end try
           end repeat
       end try
       return input
   end run
   ```
6. Save service as "Readable by All".
7. Quit the Automator application.

The service should have been saved in the `~/Library/Services` folder under the name `Readable by All.workflow`. If not, move it there.

Now when you highlight one or more files using the Finder application, you can right click and select "Readable by All" to change the permissions.

Comment: why on earth is that even the default permission? I thought that's the mistake here?

Comment: @Sumit: Ok, I am curious. If you open a Terminal application window and type the command `umask -S`, what do you get. I get `u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx`.

Comment: same for me. `u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx`

Comment: Sumit: Your defaults are set correctly. the letter `u` stands for user (you), `g` stands for group (staff on my machine) and `o` stands for other (which is everyone). The letters `r`, `w` and `x` stands for read, write and execute, respectively. Your files should be saved with everyone set to read. Someone with more experience than me is going to have to answer your question. The only thing I can suggest a automatic action which would append the everyone read permission each file added to given folder.

Comment: thank you for digging into it. An automated service is not what I'd want to do here as this is such a ridiculous issue that it has to be a mistake somewhere.